# Re-read environment variables from VBScript

Tags: vbscript, scripting, wix, windows-installer, environment-variables

I'm running a VBScript from a MSI installer (created using WiX toolset). This script checks using the PATH environment variable whether another software 
is installed or not. The installer also offers a *retry* button which runs the script again.

Now the problem is this: If the PATH environment variable is changed while my installer is running, my script will not detect that change. My script only uses the new value of the PATH environmental variable after a re-start of the installer.

So the question is this: How can I force the installer process to update its copy of the environment variables using VBScript?

**Edit:**

It looks like [this article](https://www.michaelmiklis.de/update-environment-variables-in-current-process/) explains how to solve the problem with PowerScript. But I need a solution for VBScript.

Comment: There must be a better way for you to detect that the other software is installed, such as a registry item, a ProductCode,a component guid, a file search. Note also that another MSI cannot run while your install is in progress. It's unlikely there is an easy fix because of the way MSI does environment variables, so I'd look for another detection method for that other software and not worry about a change in PATH during your install.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
With WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    .Environment("PROCESS")("PATH") = .ExpandEnvironmentStrings(Replace( _ 
        .Environment("USER")("PATH") & ";" & .Environment("SYSTEM")("PATH"), ";;", ";" _ 
    ))
End With
```

This will overwrite the in memory current process `PATH` environment variable with the information retrieved from registry for the `user` and `system` environment variables.

**note**: Previous code only updates the environment copy of the `[c|w]script` process that executes the code. It does not update the installer's copy of the environment (you can not update another process environment).

Answer (score 0):

Alternately, from `jscript` (still the `cscript` interpreter, but the jscript language)

```
// Re-read PATH vars in case they've changed
var shell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.shell");
var newPath = (shell.Environment("USER")("PATH") + ";" + shell.Environment("SYSTEM")("PATH")).replace(/;;/g, ";");
// Expand any %STRINGS% inside path and set to the new running process
shell.Environment("PROCESS")("PATH") = shell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings(newPath);

shell.Exec('myprocess.exe'); // throws exception if not found
```